# I need a REGEXP in php to search and replace "??" in dates

Tags: php, regex, string

I have data with dates written as 1992.09.02, as an example.  If the dates are not available, you end up with 1992.09.?? or 1992.??.?? or otherwise .??.??.?? if no date is known.

I need to change the ".??" to "" ie., nothing.

Here's is my attempt, but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
$text="^[1-9]. [\.\?\?] ";
str_replace("\.\?\?", " ", "$text");
```

Comment: No, don't modify the code that GSto gave you to try to turn it into a regex. `$text` should be changed to the name of the variable that contains your "data with dates". Then use *exactly* his line of code with only `$text` changed to whatever your actual variable name is.

Comment: It should be basically: `$text = '1992.??.??'; $text = str_replace(".??","",$text);` or shorter: `str_replace(".??","",'1992.??.??');` Also note that you don't have to double quote variables. `"$text" == $text` but the quoting makes the code more unreadable and is just unnecessary. Also you have to assign the return value of `str_replace` to a variable.

Answer (score 5):

```
$text = str_replace(".??","",$text);
```

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.'  Now they have two problems."  -- attr. to Jamie Zawinski

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in my php document, and it's not replacing the ".??" when the php doucument is executed. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Do I have to define the raw string as a regexp?

Comment: @ggg forget regexp, it's overkill for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ggg - is your date variable named `$text`?  You should post the relevant code so we can see what's wrong.